Same vector in row space and nullspace
This question comes from Problem 3.6.16 of Introduction to Linear Algebra (4ed) by Gilbert Strang.

Explain why $v=(1,0,-1)$ cannot be a row of $A$ and also in the nullspace.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$.  We see that $Aw=0$, so $w$ can be used as one of the basis vectors of the nullspace.  Now $w=v$, and therefore $v$ is in the nullspace.  (This conclusion is opposite to what the question suggests.)
Is this line of reasoning correct?  If not, why not?

Your $Aw \neq 0$. So $w \not\in \text{null}(A)$.

Oops, you are right.  Found that out after posting.  My bad.

The row space is the orthogonal complement to the null space. Therefore, the only shared vector is the zero vector.
See the diagram on the front cover of Strang for a beautiful picture of this.

My bad.  $Aw\ne 0$

Exactly. You would have had to assume by contrapositive that $v$ is a row of $A$ and  $Av^T=0$ then derive a contradiction. You could then say that, well, this implies $vv^T = 0$ implying that $v=0$ but $v$ is not zero. This is essentially repeating the proof that the row space is the orthogonal complement to the null space.

"See the diagram on the front cover of Strang for a beautiful picture of this."  I don't think I fully get that diagram yet.  Any good pointer(s)?

@hchar ah it’s such a beautiful idea. I didn’t get linear algebra until I understood it. Here’s prof Strang in his own words https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ggWYkes-n6E

The picture is the 4 fundamental subspaces of a matrix, and the rank nullity theorem is the one which relates their dimensions to each other. And the row and null are orthogonal, and the column and left null are orthogonal
